# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( 1_{ [ \frac{2i-2}{2n},\frac{2i-1}{2n})}(x)-1_{ [ \frac{2i-1}{2n},\frac{2i}{2n}]}(x) \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider the following sequence of functions:
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n  \left( 1_{ [ \frac{2i-2}{2n},\frac{2i-1}{2n})}(x)-1_{ [ \frac{2i-1}{2n},\frac{2i}{2n}]}(x) \right).
\end{align}

We are interested in understanding how does this function convergence pointwise as $n \to \infty$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.
That is, what is
\begin{align}
f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)
\end{align}

**Some thoughts:**
This is a periodic function that oscillates between $1$ and $-1$.  As $n$ increases the period shrinks.
I have a feeling that the limit might not exist here for all $x$.

Comment: Consider the subsequence $f_{2^m}$. You can decompose any number $x$ in its dyadic expansion where there are infinitely many $1$s.

Comment: @OliverDiaz  Could you consider adding more details and perhaps putting this as an answer?

Comment: @OliverDiaz  Ok. I think I can see that this doesn't converge almost surely. Does it converge in $L_1$?

Comment: I am responding to the question you had in your last comment in the answer section. My response  is rather long and full of LaTeX script for the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

This in response to a comment by the OP.

Consider
$$f_{2^{m-1}}=\sum^{2^{m-1}}_{j=1}\Big(\mathbb{1}_{\big(\tfrac{2j-2}{2^m},\tfrac{2j-1}{2^m}\big]}-\mathbb{1}_{\big(\tfrac{2j-1}{2^m},\tfrac{2j}{2^m}\big]}\Big)$$
Notice that
$$\begin{align}
\big(\frac{2j-2}{2^m},\frac{2j-1}{2^m}\big]&=\big(\frac{2j-2}{2^m},\frac{4j-3}{2^{m+1}}\big]\cup\big(\frac{4j-3}{2^{m+1}},\frac{2j-1}{2^m}\big]\\
&=\big(\frac{4j-4}{2^{m+1}},\frac{4j-3}{2^{m+1}}\big]\cup\big(\frac{4j-3}{2^{m+1}},\frac{4j-4}{2^{m+1}}\big]
\end{align}$$
Similarly
$$\begin{align}
\big(\frac{2j-1}{2^m},\frac{2j}{2^m}\big]&=\big(\frac{2j-1}{2^m},\frac{4j-1}{2^{m+1}}\big]\cup\big(\frac{4j-1}{2^{m+1}},\frac{2j}{2^m}\big]\\
&=\big(\frac{4j-2}{2^{m+1}},\frac{4j-1}{2^{m+1}}\big]\cup\big(\frac{4j-1}{2^{m+1}},\frac{4j}{2^{m+1}}\big]
\end{align}$$
From this
$$
|f_{2^m}-f_{2^{m-1}}|=2\sum^{2^{m-1}}_{j=1}\mathbb{1}_{\big(\tfrac{4j-3}{2^{m+1}},\tfrac{4j-2}{2^{m+1}}\big]}+\mathbb{1}_{\big(\tfrac{4j-j}{2^{m+1}},\tfrac{4j}{2^{m+1}}\big]}$$
If I did not mess up with the signs, we obtain that
$$\|f_{2^m}-f_{2^{m-1}}\|_1=2\cdot 2^{m-1}\cdot 2\cdot 2^{-(m+1)}=1$$
This shows that $\{f_n\}$ (not $\{f_{2^m}\}$) is not a Cauchy sequence in $L_1$. This also shows that $f_n$ does not converges point wise a.s. (dominated convergence would give you a contradiction).

Comment: Did you mean to say that it is NOT a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Done! I made the correction. Indeed, I meant to say the sequence is not Cauchy.